# can we use xslt transfrmation with SAX parser in Java?

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt, saxparser

I have an xm file and I have parsed it with DOM using `XSLT transformation` and stored the data into csv.

But now I want to do it in SAX as the xml file is very large.

Now my problem is Can we use xslt transformation with `SAX parser` and store the data into csv ?

I have searched everywhere but I haven't got any useful information.

This is my java code written in DOM

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

class Xml2Csv {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // Setting path for .xsl file
    File stylesheet = new File("style.xsl");

    // Setting path for Eurex xml feed file
    File xmlSource = new File("eurex_ref_data.xml");

    //Dom initialization and parse xml
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

    // Transformation of parsed xml to csv
    StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
    Source source = new DOMSource(document);
    //System.out.println(source.toString());
    System.out.println("Generating CSV File");
    Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("AID.csv"));
    transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
    System.out.println("File has been generated");
}
}
```

And this is my sample XSLT code..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>PriSetPx,TxnTm,ID,AltID,AltIDSrc</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="FIXML/Batch/SecDef">
      <xsl:variable name="secDef" select="concat(@PriSetPx,',',@TxnTm)" />
      <xsl:for-each select="Instrmt/AID">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($secDef, ',',../@ID,',',@AltID,',',@AltIDSrc,'&#xA;')"/>    
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is `SAXSource` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/sax/SAXSource.html and `StreamSource` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html so you don't need to use DOM at all to use XSLT with Java. But you have to understand that XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 in any case parse the complete XML input first into a tree representation modelling the XSLT/XPath data model. So while the native tree model of an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor might consume less memory than a DOM tree it certainly grows with the size of the input.

As for your current code, to avoid explicit use of DOM, you can simply use a `StreamSource` (or if you really want a `SAXSource`) instead of the `DOMSource` in `transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);`.

So use e.g.

```
File xmlSource = new File("eurex_ref_data.xml");
Source source = new StreamSource(xmlSource);
```

to let the XSLT processor use its native tree representation.

If you want to process very large XML documents and experience memory problems then you might want to look into XSLT 3.0 and [streaming](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#streaming-concepts) (as currently supported by Saxon 9 EE, http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/jaxp-transformation.html), for instance that stylesheet you added to your question could be easily written as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>PriSetPx,TxnTm,ID,AltID,AltIDSrc</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="FIXML/Batch/SecDef/Instrmt/AID"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AID">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::SecDef/@PriSetPx, ancestor::SecDef/@TxnTm, ../@ID, @AltID, @AltIDSrc" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then easily used with Saxon 9.7 or 9.8 EE (http://saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml) and streaming to create the CSV without any need to consume much memory as XSLT and streaming avoids building a tree of the complete input first and instead reads through the XML only once, forwards only, to process it node by node.

Or consider an XML data base like BaseX or ExistDB if you have very large input documents (where I am not sure however how good they support XSLT, they are focused on XQuery).

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your reply. May I know is SAXSource and SaxParser is same ?

Comment: Well, of course https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html is not the same as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/sax/SAXSource.html. Start reading the API or post your current code that uses DOM if you want help with moving from DOM to SAX. On the other hand I have already told you that an XSLT processor for XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 will process the complete XML input first to build a tree anyway so your memory problems might be reduced but will not vanish.

Comment: Thanks Martin, Just now updated the code which I have written in DOM and also XSLT code. Thank you very much!